# Can we transfer live App Store app from individual to company account?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, developer-program

I have an iOS app which is live on App Store and is published under my individual developer account.

If I want to register a new company and obtain an Apple developer account with the company name (may be using my own Apple ID) and then **re-publish the same app** or **just transfer it under the new company account** to have the company name as seller.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. Go to iTunes Connect → My Apps, select the app you wish to transfer, then choose Transfer App at the bottom of the page.

You will need the Team ID of the destination account to transfer apps, and the app you wish to transfer must meet the criteria set out on the page, such as disabling TestFlight before transferring.

Comment: Apple specifically mentions this case in its documentation: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f. And yes, apps can be transferred from one account to another.